# Error Code H10 on Heroku Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app hosted locally that works fine, but when I push to heroku and open the app there it won't load. I ran `heroku logs` and I got

I have already ran `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`, and have `bundle update` and `bundle install` my gem files. I ran `heroku restart` before the heroku logs.

Like I said, locally it runs fine.

[heroku logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m3df.png)

My contact.rb https://gist.github.com/Connerh92/eb8c26053d5e0329a60b28da071c5eb4

Comment: Can you post the rest of the logs around the error, that will tell you what actually went wrong?

Comment: Sure, heroku logs screenshot is above, because of low rep I can't post two links so here is the git hub if needed: https://github.com/Connerh92/blued

Comment: "Uninitialized constant Mailform" is what the error says. Looks lik contact model.rb line 1 where that is getting called. How is Mailform setup? Is it setup for production? (In production.rb, or somewhere else perhaps)

Comment: where is the Mailform gem included in your app? I can't see it in your Gemfile - are you sure your Gemfile updates are committed to your repo?